# How to display variables + text in Messagebox? Winapi32 C++

Tags: c++, variables, text

Alright so with CMD (Iostream.h) you can use << >> to pass data along. Like if I wanted to show text and a variable with text I would say.

```
cout << "You have " << numberofApples << " of apples.";
```

How can I display text and a variable into my messagebox / SetWindowText, etc. I did search around on google but I don't exactly know what you call it so I couldn't find any clean cut answers.

Thanks!

Comment: If you learned "iostream.h" from a book, burn it. If you learned it from somewhere on the web, avoid that place. "iostream.h" is not a standard C++ header.

Comment: There's a `stringstream` class that allows you to make a stream similar to `cout`, but which places the formatted output into a string so you can do things with it (display in messagebox, send across network, etc)

Comment: I agree with @BenVoigt, though beware that `stringstream` is as inefficient as it is easy. If you're writing a simple program, or one where performance doesn't matter, it should be just fine to use `stringstream`. Otherwise, you'll want to look into more advanced string formatting techniques (not for the faint of heart).

Comment: It's true that `stringstream` may not be terribly efficient, but the stated purpose is generating a message box, so there are not any performance concerns.  @BenVoigt should write his comment as an answer. I'll +1 it.

Comment: @JPhi1618: Exactly, it's perfectly adequate to perform operations at the speed of the user

Answer (score 2):

There's a `std::stringstream` class that allows you to make a stream similar to `std::cout`, but which places the formatted output into a string so you can do things with it (display in messagebox, send across network, etc)

For example, using your code with a message box would look like

```
#include <sstream>

#include <windows.h>
```

...

```
std::stringstream box_message;
box_message << "You have " << numberofApples << " of apples.";
MessageBoxA(0, box_message.str().c_str(), "My Message Box", MB_OK);
```

There's also `std::wstringstream` which can be used with Unicode (UCS-2) to display Eastern languages (and use `MessageBoxW`)